# How to find out that a process started Ok

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

I am trying to find out if there is a good way to know if a `Process` is started correctly.
I use the following code :

```
        if (!_process.Start())
        {
            throw new Exception("Component {0} failed to start.".FormatWith(component.Name));
        }

        if (!_process.IsMyProcessRunning())
        {
            throw new Exception("Component {0} failed to start.".FormatWith(component.Name));
        }

static public class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsMyProcessRunning(this Process process)
    {
        return !process.HasExited && process.Id != 0 ;
    }
}
```

i guess that the `Start()` method is faster and sometimes i get the exception and sometimes no. my process is starting a faulted program.